# Java using instanceof to check the class with same name in different packages

Tags: java, instanceof

I have two files with same name in different `packages`, in certain function i need to check the argument passed is of the `instanceof` which class it is.

Eg.

```
if(input instanceof x.y.test) {
      //do something
    } else if(input instanceof x.y.z test) {
      //do something
    }
```

But in many places I read that using `instanceof` is not a good practice. What kinda of alternate I can apply here.

*Note*: One file is of `.groovy` and other one is `.java` file, but both representing the same domain

Comment: What does `instanceof` has to do with files with identical names?

Comment: One file is of .groovy and other one is .java file, but both representing the same domain

Comment: @Tichodroma I have the same question but giving the OP the benefit of the doubt, it is possible that the code deals with a scenario where multiple libraries have the same class name and a decision must be made based on what type of object was created. +1 from me because the question is pretty clear.

Comment: @Suganthan Please [edit] your question and explain this important point.

Comment: @Tichodroma This was pretty clear to me. Not sure why the question needs editing.

Comment: I think you might be mixing packages and folders.

Comment: @Suganthan Good that you did clarify that: instaceof checks objects for their class! You can't use it at all to differentiate between a groovy text file; and another text file ending with .java. For that, you can use the standard java file classes; where you would make sure to compare absolute file names.

Comment: @Jägermeister, comparing file name wouldn't be a standard solution right, still we have to use reflection which is much costlier

Comment: @PM77-1, thanks i did the edit

Comment: @Suganthan The question: do you want to compare **files**; or objects, which were created using `new`? You only need instanceof for the later case. And yes, then using "instanceof" (simply using the absolute class name, including the complete path) is to be preferred over reflection.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit general claim, to say "instanceof is a bad practice". It depends on the requirements, technical limitations, personal taste etc.

However, it is a point worth considering. **Sometimes** it means someone missed an opportunity to use polymorphism. For example, if your code says

```
if (input instanceof x.y.test){
    greeting = "hello from xy";
}
else if (input instanceof x.y.z.test){
   greeting = "hello from xyz";
}
```

Then it might be nicer if each 'test' had a method 'greet()':

```
greeting = input.greet();
// where class x.y.test  has public String greet(){return "hello from xy";}
// and class x.y.z.test  has public String greet(){return "hello from xyz";}
```

I say **might**, because it has a strong advantage: people can now add lots of other 'test' implementations, and your main code will accept them seamlessly without having to add 'if-else'.
However, it might also have disadvantages: if you feel it's wrong for your 'test' class to be responsible for the greeting calculation; or if it's a 3rd party outside your control. That's why I'm against generalizations.

There are more elaborate solutions - e.g. lookup the '**visitor**' design pattern.